# Iterations indices processed by OpenMP threads

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp

I am running a for loop with openmp static load balancing. I´d like to print the first and the last iteration processed by each thread (a.k.a the first and last value of `i`, for every thread).
The loop looks like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) private(i)
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
//loop code
}
```

I am well aware that OpenMP doc specifies the range of iterations to be divided equally in static schedule although I would like to print the iteration values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember the index in a private variable that is initialized to a marker value (-1):

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int index = -1;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        //loop code
        if (index == -1) {
            printf("%d: start %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
        }
        index = i;
    }
    printf("%d: last %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zulan. I can replace `after last` by `last` and `index-1`, right?

Comment: Actually, `index` shows the last `i` that was processed in the loop (e.g. `99` for `n=100`). Note that you cannot directly use `i`, because it's value is normally unspecified per the OpenMP standard.